# Jetty customized Error handler class is called but no throwable object is Got

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am using Jetty 9.3.3. I implemented my custom error handler class, the handle method was called but can't see why cause no throwable object is got:

Here is the code of my class :

```
public class TestExecuterServerErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler{

    private Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());  

    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        logger.systemWriteOutput("handeling error", 3);

        ByteArrayISO8859Writer writer= new ByteArrayISO8859Writer(4096);
        Throwable th = (Throwable)request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION); 

        response.setContentType("text/xml");

        if(th!=null)
        {
            writeResponseError(response.getStatus(), th, writer);
            th.printStackTrace();
        }

        writer.flush();
        response.setContentLength(writer.size());       
        writer.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
        writer.destroy();        
    }
}
```

The output:

```
handeling error
handeling error
```

how can I print the cause of the call of the handle method?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when using Jetty and Jersey. I solved it by setting the attribute `ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR` to `true`, preventing Jersey from returning the response prematurely (prior to attaching the exception to the request object).